# Wix Cabinet Caching Not Working

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I can't seem to get wix cabinet caching to work.

I have

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CabinetCreationThreadCount>3</CabinetCreationThreadCount>
    <CabinetCachePath>cabs</CabinetCachePath>
    <ReuseCabinetCache>True</ReuseCabinetCache>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

in the wixproj.

```
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="contents.cab" EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="mszip"/>

<Media Id="2" Cabinet="static.cab" EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="mszip"/>
```

in the wxs

and a component that I know 100% never ever changes marked with

```
     <Component DiskId="2" ...
```

I see the cab files generated in the cabs directory, but each time I build, I see the modified time of the cab file change, which suggests that it's regenerated the cabinet instead of reusing the one from the cache.

Using Wix 3.6

How can I get this working or debug the problem further?

Answer (score 0):

Are you building or rebuilding (i.e. `/t:build` or `/t:rebuild`)? The WiX import will remove generated files when rebuilding. It's also possible that this is happening even if you are simply building. Generate a verbose log by passing `/v:diag` to MSBuild but be sure to redirect to a file like so:

```
msbuild /t:build /v:diag
```

If that does not show the CAB file(s) being deleted, I recommend checking out http://wixtoolset.org for their support channel.